# Do we need a comma to separate these two sentences?

Tags: grammar, commas

Which one of these sentences is correct?

> 1 *By using this method, they found that sugar is important in diet.*
>     2 *By using this method they found that sugar is important in diet.*

Do we need a comma to separate two sentences?

Comment: Please, write a full sentence. Your example is a sentence fragment.

Comment: More important than the comma here is the phrase "so impotent".  If you mean "important" you should change "so" to "very". But if you do indeed mean "impotent", then eliminate "so".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CMOS (The Chicago Manual of Style) leaves the choice  on whether to follow introductory adverbial clauses with commas with you:-)

It recommends though - but not very forcefully - skipping the comma for short ones.